# Ubuntu 20.04 installation error

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, usb-installation

I'm going for dual boot, using win 10 atm.

I followed all the steps on how to make a bootable USB stick from [the Ubuntu.com tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) : Create a USB Strick on Windows.

When i boot the USB, it gives me this menu
[image: menu]

After I click enter on the first option (the one that is just saying 'Ubuntu') it goes to a black screen and goes to this
[image: errorlog]

I am stuck at the last picture.

Thank you.

Comment: Did the safe graphics work option in GRUB work and do you have an Nvidia graphics card?

Comment: I used Nvidia GPU yes and when i run it in the safe graphics it gives this https://imgur.com/a/6s92uk3

Comment: With Rufus expand the advanced section and uncheck Quick format and check "Check device for bad blocks" with 1 pass. This will take a LONG time depending on the size of the usb stick. It will check for bad blocks and totally overwrite the data on the drive.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the I/O error in the pictures I would suggest:

- If possible try another memory stick
- Re download the iso as it may be corrupt download

Comment: I re downloaded the ISO file, it didnt  change anything, but i will try with another USB stick. Thank you.